# BizTalk error Schema Not Found

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, btahl7

I'm receiving an HL7 2.3 ORU schema.  I've configured the appropriate party to use a schema namespace of "http://mycompany.ca/application/HL7/2X/2.3/1"

I've built my custom HL7 Schema, ad set the targetNamespace to "http://mycompany.ca/application/HL7/2X/2.3/1", and ensured it has a root element of "ORU_R01_23_GLO_DEF".

I've deployed the schema to biztalk by importing it, then running the msi.
I can see that my BIzTalk application has the schema in it, and I can see that the MSI installed the schema on the drive.

When I send an HL7 to my receive location, I get an error in the evenlog:

Error happened in body during parsing 
Error # 1

Alternate Error Number: 301
Alternate Error Description: Schema http://mycompany.ca/application/HL7/2X/2.3/1#ORU_R01_23_GLO_DEF not found
Alternate Encoding System: HL7-BTA

From this, I can tell that the party resolution worked correctly, but can't figure out why it can not find the schema.

Comment: I presume that you bounced the Host Instance running the Receive Location so it would pickup the schema deployment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BizTalk HL7 Adaptor (BTAHL7) error with MSH trailing delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956731/biztalk-hl7-adaptor-btahl7-error-with-msh-trailing-delimiters)